# Wanting to change the colour of a shape in Powerpoint dependant on data in excel

Tags: excel, powerpoint

I have created a visual in powerpoint where I want to change the colour of a shape dependant on data I have in excel.
For example my data set lists work activities that I have represented in an excel powerpoint. When I type 100% into the completion column in the excel sheet I am wanting it to change the colour of the shape of the related activty in the powerpoint.

Thanks in advance.

I have been trying to link the shape to the data set with no success so far.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.